# Io Failure when try to get data of parsefile

Tags: android, amazon-ec2

```
Error throw :I/O failure
```

My code

```
Parsefile thumbnail=products.get(0).getParseFile("image");
     if (thumbnail != null) {
    
            thumbnail.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    
    
                        picsbitmap.put(itemname,bmp);
                        Log.d("nwck", String.valueOf(picsbitmap.size()));
    
    
    
                    } else {
    
                        Log.d("enaproblem",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
    
        }
```

My thumbnail is not
null but I get an exception on the done method , I try to retrieve png file and picsbitmap is hashmap<String,Bitmap> type and is there any way to get image from Aws server

Comment: `I get an exception` Well..... where ? How? Which statement? Which exception?

Comment: `picsbitmap is hashmap<String,Bitmap> type` Instead of telling such things afterwards you should have that defined in your code.

Comment: first of all !! I admire your tendency to help stranger man@blackapps

Comment: exception on LOg.("enna probelm",e.get localised messagge);

Comment: exception on LOg.("enna probelm",e.get localised messagge); @blackapps

Comment: Why dont you just decode the array when data not is null?

Comment: `My thumbnail is not null but` Very confusing name. You mean your parsefile instance is not null. Better: ParseFile parseFile = ..

Comment: I dont know how to do that buddy@blackapps

Comment: ??? To do what exactly?

Comment: YEs my thumbnail is Parse instance@blackapps

Comment: if (data!=null) {  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); }

Comment: why are u trying to decode data, the problem  is I am getting exception on done method@blackapps

Comment: Well you want some data. Just try it. Maybe the exception does not matter.

Comment: done() is not giving me data its just throwing exception , I don't what causes it can u please help to identify it@blackapps

Comment: Impossible. If done would throw then your log statement would not be called.

Comment: done() has two parameters. You are only looking at e and never checking data for null or value.

Comment: yes just now  i checked data value , it is null @blackapps